# Android-Activity closes upon starting get content intent

Tags: android

In my code when user selects a button from actions menu.It opens a select image inent.
It works fine until here..

**But by the time i return after selecting the image.My original activity that started it is killed.I don't get any force close** or error in logcat. At least from warning.

Heres my code can you help me?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    final android.view.SubMenu sharephoto = menu.findItem(
            R.id.action_settings).getSubMenu();

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        selectImageFromGallery();

        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void selectImageFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            2);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.w("upload", "entered");
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Log.w("upload", "enteredin");

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Log.w("upload", picturePath);
        // decodeFile(picturePath);
        // mimetype = getMimeType(picturePath);
        // bmpG=new BitmapFactory().decodeFile(picturePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: try using smaller sample images like less than 10kb

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you don't return to your activity, or just that the system is recreating your activity, and it was for some reason gone?  Its possible that your app will be shut down while you're off doing other things, and restarted when you return.  That's just one of those Android things.

If its the former, that you simply never return to your activity, that's a different discussion.  You'll need to post more code.

Comment: Currently i dont return to the activity.Though i found the reason of it after i studied lifr cycle of startActivityForResult..It calls the onpause first...the problem was here i had specified finish() in onpause so my activity was getting killed